# Syntax to declare an Arraylist containg an Arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class which I called `Hour`, and I declared an `Arraylist <day>`,  which contains 24 elements of `Hour` class.

Now, I would like to declare an Arraylist of `Arraylist<day>` but I am not sure about the syntax for that.

```
ArrayList <Hour> day  = new ArrayList <Hour> (); //// just for test now 
ArrayList <day> test  = new ArrayList <day> ();
```

the problem is in this line

```
ArrayList <day> test  = new ArrayList <day> ();
```

Comment: Please try to make your title actually reflect your question. *"declare about Arraylist of Arraylist in java"* could be about anything vaguely related to `ArrayList`s.

Answer (score 3):

Correct syntax is

```
     List<ArrayList<Hour>> = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Hour>>();
```

Comment: Don’t make your life unnecessarily hard: `List<List<Hour>> = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @Holger Agreed. If Ibrahem is using Java 1.7 or 1.7 + :)